# Import Scripts into HTML UI in google-apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

First of all, thanks for reading.

I was trying to make some kind of code repository using a spreadsheet, google-apps-script and HTML UI.

I though that using CodeMirror to highlighting would be wonderful, but, when I try to use it in the HTML page for the UI I get tons of errors like:

> Secuencia de comandos o contenido HTML no válido:
>
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:1+1 - 2: Expected      not <
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:1+1 - 8+32:
> Skipping     malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:1+1 - 8+33:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:9+16 -
> 21: Expected  not push(
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:9+11 - 35:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:9+37 - 51:
> Expected  not 'UA-200051-15'
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:9+37
> - 53: Skipping malformed content http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:9+11 - 54:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:10+16 - 21:
> Expected  not push(
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:10+11 - 38:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:10+40 - 50:
> Expected  not 'gdriv.es'
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:10+40 - 52:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:10+11 - 53:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:11+16 - 21:
> Expected  not push(
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:11+11 - 40:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:11+11 - 41:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:12+11 - 12:
> Expected  not (
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:12+11 -  22:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:12+11 -
> 16+12: Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:16+12 - 13:
> Expected  not )
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:16+12 - 15:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:16+12 - 16:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:17+9 - 10:
> Expected  not <
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:17+9 - 27+8:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css:17+9 - 27+8:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js:1+1 - 2:
> Unexpected token < http://script.google.com/vbscript.js:1+1 - 2:
> Unexpected token <
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:1+1 - 2: Expected
>  not <
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:1+1 - 8+32:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:1+1 - 8+33:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:9+16 - 21: Expected
>  not push(
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:9+11 - 35: Skipping
> malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:9+37 - 51: Expected
>  not 'UA-200051-15'
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:9+37 - 53: Skipping
> malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:9+11 - 54: Skipping
> malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:10+16 - 21:
> Expected  not push(
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:10+11 - 38:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:10+40 - 50:
> Expected  not 'gdriv.es'
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:10+40 - 52:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:10+11 - 53:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:11+16 -
> 21: Expected  not push( http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:11+11 - 40:
> Skipping malformed content
> http://gdriv.es/danielo515/codemirror/doc/docs.css:11+11 - 41:
> Skipping malformed content

Sorry, I don't know how to indent it.
Is it possible to achieve what I'm trying?
Which should be the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript in HtmlService is sanitized via Caja, and lots of existing libraries are unfortunately not compatible with Caja. The Apps Script and Caja teams are hard at work at improving this situation by relaxing the restrictions as much as possible, but so far there is nothing to announce.

Comment: Sad to hear that.
Is it possible to make a request to an external server and publish the higligted text by html? or is it also forbidden?

Comment: Nothing is forbidden; some things just don't work yet. Give it a try.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I don't mean forbidden, I mean not possible because the bouncer (AKA CAJA) doesn't let it. But you're right. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the links you provide - try removing the *:1+1* suffix and they will load successfully.